# comparing contents of two files using python

Tags: python

I have a file name exclusionlist.txt and i have contents in it like

```
          import os
          import re
          import subprocess
          ......and many more
```

I have another file named libraries.txt and the contents of this file are

```
         import mymodule
         import empmodule,os
         import subprocess
         import datetime,logging,re
         .......and many more
```

My question is that from python how to know that the contents which are in exclusionlist.txt is also present in libraries.txt since here it is jumbled up..

```
         f = open('exclusionlist.txt', 'r')
         f.read()

         f1= open('libraries.txt', 'r')
         f1.read()

        if (//Is contents of f1 present in f2):
             print libraries found
        else:
             print not found

        f.close()
        f1.close()
```

Comment: If your goal here is to stop python code from loading certain modules (i.e. run code in a sandbox environment) then you might want to have a look at the rexec module, which provides (with caveats) a "restricted execution framework".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set intersection:

```
def readImports(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            # lines of form "import ___,___"
            # assuming not of form "from ___ import ___ [as ___]"
            if 'import' in line:
                modules = line.split('import')[1]
                for module in modules.split(','):
                    yield module.strip()

linesInExclusion = set(readImports('exclusionlist.txt'))
linesInLibraries = set(readImports('libraries.txt'))

print(linesInExclusion.intersection(linesInLibraries))
```

You can do `return (line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()!='')` if you want to be perfect...

Comment: I think you want intersection (contents in both, no?) and the above won't catch the duplication of "re", as it's not a duplication of the line "import re".  I think he needs to split the rhs and then intersect the sets.

Comment: @DSM oops thanks, I meant intersection, it's late... and you are also right, updating...

Comment: whats in both: linesInExclusion&linesInLibraries, whats in linesInExclusion but not in linesInLibraries: linesInExclusion-linesInLibraries, similarly: linesInLibraries-linesInLibraries, whats not in both: linesInExclusion^linesInLibraries

Comment: This is good. I think you need to `yield module.strip()` to deal with line-endings and other whitespace, though.

Comment: What robert king means, is that there is syntax for this (I chose not to use it for clarity). The syntax is: intersection:`&`, difference:`-`, symmetricdifference:`^`

Comment: Thanks u all..I will accept this answer. My question was more generic,May be i should have asked it more precisely.Please look into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235377/comapre-file-contents-using-python