# compare file contents using python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comparing contents of two files using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235126/comparing-contents-of-two-files-using-python)

I have a file name globalexclusionlist.txt and i have contents in it like

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <iostream>
      import subprocess
      import java.sql.*;import java.io.*;
      ruby library
      show tables; 

      ......and many more
```

I have another file named libraries.txt and the contents of this file are

```
     import mymodule
     import empmodule,os
     import subprocess
     import java.sql.*
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <iostream>
     import datetime,logging,re
     import java.io.*;
     .......and many more
```

My question is that from python how to know that the contents which are in exclusionlist.txt is also present in libraries.txt since here it is jumbled up..

```
     f = open('globalexclusionlist.txt', 'r')
     f.read()

     f1= open('libraries.txt', 'r')
     f1.read()

    if (//Is contents of f1 present in f2):
         print libraries found
    else:
         print not found

    f.close()
    f1.close()
```

Comment: possibly duplicate, that post was answered for only comparing python imports and i want to do it for all.. like the mentioned above..

Comment: So why don't you modify [the accepted answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235126/comparing-contents-of-two-files-using-python/6235203#6235203)? And ask a specific question if you have a problem, rather than expecting people to write code for you?

Comment: I have accepted the answer..and also have wrote a comment

Comment: I'm not suggesting You modify the question, rather that you actually make some attempt at coding this yourself, using te previous answer as a base. This is a site for programmers, not for people wanting software to be written for them!

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I know that, but the point i am making is that the previous question was not appropriate which i agree and that is why i asked another question.And to your point i didnt ask any software to be written i just want to know the methods.Please let me close this question if it bothers u so much..And i do not want non technical suggestions on this site..Any way thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)